# Why output of 'p' and '&p' is not same for 'int* p' in c++;?

Tags: c++, pointers

Here `p` is `int` type of pointer variable.In my code as per I understand output will be same for two line.But it doesn't.So I want to konw why it doesn.t?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int* p;

    cout<<p<<endl; //0x41c2de
    cout<<&p<<endl;  //0x28ff0c
}
```

**Question: Why output of two line is not same??**

Comment: Because they related to diferents things. p is the content of the variable, while &p is the address of this variable

Comment: Why would it be the same?

Comment: There is nothing special about pointers. It follows the same rules as if you wrote `int p;`.